# Создание элементов в C#

Tags: c#

Вот скажите, на форуме можно добавлять елементы через ToolBox, а можно ли тоже самое сделать через код? При этом определить его расположение, цвет, интервал и.т.д короче св-ва... для примера давайте возьмём Timer1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я так понимаю в вопросе опечатка и имеется ввиду ФОРМА. Если так, то конечно можно добавлять любые контролы на форму программно:

```
var btn = new Button();
btn.Location = new Point(10, 10);
btn.Text = "test";
btn.Click += btn_Click;
this.Controls.Add(btn);
```

На форму можно добавить только объекты классов, являющихся предками [Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx). Что же касается таймера, то он не наследник данного типа и на форме не отображается, для его использования достаточно создать в коде формы объект таймера и использовать по своей нужде - на форму его добавлять нельзя и не нужно.

UPD: кстате если заглянуть в код метода *InitializeComponent()* конструктора формы, то именно там вы и обнаружите код для добавления контролов на форму, к-й генерирует студия.

Comment: ВСЁ РАБОТАЕТ! Спасибо!